# React functional component cannot read undefined properties (reading map)

Tags: reactjs, json, typescript, dictionary, components

I am trying to parse a json object into a functional component. `NavBar` component takes argument `links` as an array (via stringify json). This is then passed to `Button` where it is used to render buttons.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Code for NavBar:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import styles from './Components.module.css';
import logo from '../media/logo.png';
import Button from './Button';
import Search from './Search';

type Link = {
    label: string;
    href: string;
};

const Nav: React.FC<{ links: Link[] }> = ({ links }) =>  {
    return (
        <nav className={styles.navbar}>
            <div className={styles.logo_container}>
                <a href={'index'}>
                    <img src={logo} className={styles.logo} alt="logo" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <Button links={links}/>
        </nav>
    )
}

export default Nav;
```

Code for Button:

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './Components.module.css';

type Link = {
    label: string;
    href: string;
};

const Button: React.FC<{ links: Link[] }> = ({ links }) => {
    return (
        <div className={styles['links_container']}>
            {links.map((link: Link) => {
                return (
                    <div key={link.href} className={styles['link']}>
                        <a href={link.href}>
                            {link.label}
                        </a>
                    </div>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
};

export default Button;
```

Comment: Can you share console.log(links) before your map?

Comment: Try to get first the initial value of links; the code is good. All depend on the value of links (is an array? check it)

Comment: its undefined, though I do not know why as it believe it's passed correctly

Comment: const linksString = JSON.stringify(data);
const links = JSON.parse(linksString).links; the parse is what turns it to undefined

Comment: @user17976264 you can update this in above code to include optional chaining before accessing map as
            {links?.map((link: Link) => { , 
Which will prevent from your code throwing error so that you debug further  and check wether you are actually getting array of link objects to iterate.